# Mobile data won't turn on till reboot

Tags: mobile-data, samsung-vibrant

I'm using a Samsung Vibrant (aka Samsung T959 Galaxy S) (Installed Jellybean). Sometimes when I keep mobile data off for a while, it doesn't turn on. I have to reboot it to make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a network problem and might not have anything to do with your phone. Try using data services by some other provider.

Also, try re-configuring the APN settings.

Comment: It might not be. I had a older device which will behave like this on Custom ROMs(JB) but not on stock ROM(GB). The problem was APNs would simply vanish. If OP is facing the same issue, then the ROM is to blame.

Comment: If you're using a custom ROM then it might be the ROM's fault. You have to install another ROM(preferably stable) and try your luck.

Comment: I am no longer using that device, switched to Nexus 5 :)

Comment: Looks like a problem with the ROM. Switched to Nexus 5 and now it works fine. Thanks